# Power BI - users unable to view new dashboards in new workspace, but can view dashboards in other workspaces

Tags: powerbi

Users have power bi free licenses.

I have given users access to a new workspace and an old workspace, where they can view the dashboard in the old workspace but not the new workspace.

The error message they get when trying to access the dashboard in the new workspace is 'upgrade to power bi pro', but they do not need the pro license to access the old workspace.

In the both workspaces I have added the users permissions to view the dataset, app and also added then to the users in the workspace.

Any ideas on how I can get the users access to the new dashboard without granting them a pro license?

I have been asked to create the new workspace so want to use this rather than the old workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To share resources with other users, both the owner and the other user needs Power BI Pro licenses. The only exception is when there is a dedicated capacity assigned to the workspace, in which case only the publisher needs Power BI Pro license. So it looks like in your case there is a dedicated capacity ([Power BI Premium](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi-premium/) or [Power BI Embedded](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/power-bi-embedded/)) assigned to the old workspace, but not to the new one. Also see [Configure and manage capacities in Power BI Premium](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-premium-manage).

Quote from [Ways to share your work in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-how-to-collaborate-distribute-dashboards-reports):

> No matter which option you choose, to share your content you need a Power BI Pro license, or the content needs to be in a Premium capacity.